# Read next character (full unicode code point) from Java input stream

Tags: java, utf-8

I need to parse UTF-8 input (from a text file) character by character (and by character I mean full UTF-8 character (UTF-8 code point), not Java's char).

What approach should I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's [CharSequence.codePoints()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/CharSequence.html#codePoints())

For example:

```
String text = Files.readString(Path.of("test.txt"));

IntStream codePoints = text.codePoints();

// do something with the code points
codePoints.forEach(codePoint -> System.out.println(codePoint));
```

Comment: yeah, what if it's a stream - how do you read codepoint by codepoint instead sluping up the whole file into a string first?

Comment: It may be `String text = Files.readString(Paths.get("test.txt"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);`

Comment: @英語は苦手 Thanks :-) Improved the code example as you suggested

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
public class CodePointReader {

    Reader in;

    public CodePointReader(Reader in) {
        this.in = in;
    }

    public int read() throws IOException {
        int first = in.read();
        if (first == -1)
            return -1;
        if (!Character.isHighSurrogate((char)first))
            return first;
        int second = in.read();
        if (second == -1)
            throw new IOException("low surrogate expected after %d".formatted(first));
        if (!Character.isLowSurrogate((char)second))
            throw new IOException("invalid surrogate pair (%d, %d)".formatted(first, second));
        return Character.toCodePoint((char)first, (char)second);
    }
}
```

and

```
@Test
public void testCodePointReader() throws IOException {
    String s = "";
    CodePointReader reader = new CodePointReader(new StringReader(s));
    assertEquals(s.codePointAt(0), reader.read());
    assertEquals(s.codePointAt(2), reader.read());
    assertEquals(-1, reader.read());
}
```

Answer (score -5):

You can do this easily with an InputStreamReader by using the read() method. The read method will return an int which is a code point. Check out more here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/stream.html

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("test.txt");
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis, "UTF8");
//Use isr.read() to read character by character.
```

Comment: In the example in the link provided, there is: `int ch;
        while ((ch = in.read()) > -1) {
            buffer.append((char)ch);
        }`. But what happens if `ch` (an `int`) cannot fit into 2-byte `char`?

Comment: Good point. You could encounter code points higher than 2^16. Luckily the StringBuilder/StringBuffer classes have methods: appendCodePoint(int codePoint) to deal with that.

Comment: The `int` returned by `Reader.read()` is a character, **not** a code point.